# Show/Hide javascript query

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made this html test website to test show/hide javascript.

When I load the page, I would like to show the first page but in my website everything is hidden '*till I click on a button*'.

```
<html>
    <head><title>Test</title>
        <script>
                function toggle(target){

                var artz = document.getElementsByClassName('article');
                var targ = document.getElementById(target);  
                var isVis = targ.style.display=='block';

                for(var i=0;i<artz.length;i++){
                 artz[i].style.display = 'none';
                }

                targ.style.display = isVis?'none':'block';

                return false;
                }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#" onclick="toggle('about');">About Us</a>
        <a href="#" onclick="toggle('contact');">Contact</a>
        <a href="#" onclick="toggle('products');">Products</a>

        <div class="article" id="about" style="display:none;">ABOUT PAGE...</div>
        <div class="article" id="contact" style="display:none;">CONTACT PAGE...</div>
        <div class="article" id="products" style="display:none;">PRODUCTS PAGE...</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are using pure javascript why added jquery tag

Comment: see my answer and fiddle

Comment: Why don't you just remove `style="display:none;"` from the element you want to show?

Comment: because this is how i hide all. but i would like to display first page when i load the page

Comment: So you want at the same time to hide all and not hide all (show the first page)? Doesn't make much sense to me. If you don't want to hide the first page, remove the `display:none` CSS rule from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that's because all your elements are hidden and the toggle-function is only invoked on click.

Use this:

```
window.onload = function(){
  toggle('about'); //or whichever page you'd like to show on startup
}
```

This function is invoked on page-load and calls the toggle-function, providing the content that shoud be shown.

Alternatively, you could just change your `style="display:none;"` to `style="display:block;"` in the HTML for the content that should be shown on page-load.